# Find closest number in a column and output the index number in Pandas DataFrame Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a DataFrame as below and struggling to get the index number of the closest number in points column.

```
      name   age   points
0     mike   26    150
1     john   34    100
2   gracia   27    250
3    Shawn   31    400
4     lily   24    350
```

Suppose user inputs `468` i want to get the closest row in points column index number would be `3`.
Now i have other DataFrame that i am want the code to work with that has different column difference like for the above DataFrame the difference is 50 other DataFrame has difference of 100 some have 10, 20 etc like below.

```
      name   age   points
0     mike   26       30
1     john   34       10
2   gracia   27       20
3    Shawn   31      120
4     lily   24       90


      name   age   points
0     mike   26      1000
1     john   34      2300
2   gracia   27      2500
3    Shawn   31      4000
4     lily   24      3500


      name   age   points
0     mike   26      150
1     john   34      100
2   gracia   27      250
3    Shawn   31      400
4     lily   24      350
```

I am looking for a solution that works for all DataFrame that as difference of 1,10, 20, 50, 100 ,500 etc in points column.

Comment: Use (df['points']-input_number).argmin(), maybe abs() is needed

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa you need to take the absolute value of the subtracted numbers `df['points'].sub(input_number).abs().idxmin()`

Comment: @AlfredoMaussa thank you for your answer adding abs() worked like It_is_Chris suggested